# Stored procedure not returning recordset

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, stored-procedures, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm stuck with the below. I have a stored procedure which takes a date and Manager ID as parameters to generate a Resultset

```
CREATE PROCEDURE[ACT].[sp_getAllocations]
    @dtmReportDate DATE,
    @ManagerID BIGINT,
    @type nvarchar(MAX) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        ARCVTADMIN.tblEmployee.strFirstName + ' ' + ARCVTADMIN.tblEmployee.strSurname AS Name, 
        COUNT(ACT.tblActivity.employeeID) AS Workstate, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN ACT.tblactivity.statusTypeID = 4 AND ACT.tblActivity.dtmCompletedDate = @dtmReportDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Completed, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN ACT.tblActivity.statusReasonID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NewLeads, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN ACT.tblContact.dtmLoggedDate = @dtmReportDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Worked
    FROM            
        ACT.tblContact 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN
        ACT.tblActivity ON ACT.tblContact.activityID = ACT.tblActivity.activityID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        ARCVTADMIN.tblEmployee ON ACT.tblActivity.employeeID = ARCVTADMIN.tblEmployee.employeeID 
                               AND ACT.tblActivity.employeeID = ARCVTADMIN.tblEmployee.employeeID 
                               AND ACT.tblActivity.employeeID = ARCVTADMIN.tblEmployee.employeeID
                               AND ACT.tblActivity.employeeID = ARCVTADMIN.tblEmployee.employeeID
    GROUP BY 
        ARCVTADMIN.tblEmployee.strFirstName + ' ' + ARCVTADMIN.tblEmployee.strSurname, 
        ARCVTADMIN.tblEmployee.managerID
    HAVING        
        (ARCVTADMIN.tblEmployee.managerID = @ManagerID)
END
```

NB: ARCVTADMIN, ACT are Schema names

This stored procedure works fine when I run it within SQL Server like

```
Declare @D nVarchar(max);
EXECUTE ACT.sp_getAllocations @dtmReportDate = '20161220', @ManagerID = 91, @type=@D out
Print @D
```

The below is the result produced by the stored procedure when I execute it within SQL Server

```
Name            Workstate   Completed    NewLeads    Worked
===========================================================
Nikki Furnell     4999          0        3434           0
Harriet Johnson     10          0           0           0
Claire Rowe        138          0          17           0
Carina Hughes        4          0           0           0
```

I have a function in a Class Module as below

```
Public Function getSPRecordset(dtmReportDate As String, managerID As Long) As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strType As String
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
If Not (isConnectionOpen()) Then
OpenConnection
End If

Set ADOCom = New ADODB.Command
ADOCom.ActiveConnection = ADOConn
ADOCom.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
ADOCom.CommandText = "[ACT].[sp_getAllocations]"
ADOCom.Parameters.Refresh

ADOCom.Parameters.Append ADOCom.CreateParameter("@dtmReportDate", adDate,   adParamInput, 10, dtmReportDate)
ADOCom.Parameters.Append ADOCom.CreateParameter("@ManagerID", adBigInt, adParamInput, 10, managerID)
ADOCom.Parameters.Append ADOCom.CreateParameter("@type", adVarChar, adParamOutput, 10000, strType)
Set rst = ADOCom.Execute
Set getSPRecordset = rst
End Function
```

I'm trying to retrieve the resultset and assign it to my form and I'm trying the below.

```
Public Sub loadAllocation()
Dim objSS As clsSQLServer
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Set objSS = New clsSQLServer
Set rst = objSS.getSPRecordset(Me.dtmReportDate, Me.managerID)
Set Me.frmTeamDashboardWorkstate.Form.Recordset = rst ***Error Line ****
set rst=nothing
End Sub
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Where is loadAllocation being called from? What is `Me` in this context? Is frmTeamDashboardWorkstate a sub-form? Are you intending this recordset to be held open across the network for all the time that the form is open? If not then you should use a 'disconnected' recordset. Use `rst.CursorLocation = adUseClient` before setting it (probably need to `Dim` it as `New ADODB.Recordset` to do this).

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @Skippy Thank you for your response. Below are the clarifications...

Comment: @Skippy
Where is loadAllocation being called from?**from a OnChange Event Combo Box (ManagerID)**
What is Me in this context? **Parent Form of frmTeamDashboardWorkstate**  
 Is frmTeamDashboardWorkstate a sub-form? **Yes**
Are you intending this recordset to be held open across the network for all the time that the form is open? If not then you should use a 'disconnected' recordset. **Not Sure but Only need to display data** Use rst.CursorLocation = adUseClient before setting it (probably need to Dim it as New ADODB.Recordset to do this).**Still No Luck**

Comment: @marc_s Thank you for your suggestion and I shall make a quick CTRL + H thing as soon as i'm done with this issue...

Answer (score 0):

OK, what I think you need to do is...

Firstly, is your `Public Sub loadAllocation()` in a separate module or is it in the parent form's module? I would recommend having it as a `Private Sub` within the parent form's module.

Secondly you need to declare rst as a module level variable in the parent form's module. It needs to stay in scope after `loadAllocation()` has run. So right at the top of the module, before any Sub or Function definitions, and just after the `Option Compare Database` and `Option Explicit`, add in

```
Private rst As ADODB.Recordset
```

Then I would re-code your procedure as

```
Private Sub loadAllocation()
On Error GoTo PROC_ERR

    Dim objSS As New clsSQLServer

    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
    rst.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    Set rst = objSS.getSPRecordset(Me.dtmReportDate, Me.managerID)
    'You could put some Debug.Print statements in here just to check that rst has retrieved some data'
    If rst.State = adStateOpen Then
        Set Me.frmTeamDashboardWorkstate.Form.Recordset = rst
        frmTeamDashboardWorkstate.Form.Requery
        rst.ActiveConnection = Nothing
    End If

PROC_EXIT:
    'Put any clean-up code in here'
    Exit Sub

PROC_ERR:
    'Put your preferred error handling code in here'
    Resume PROC_EXIT

End Sub
```

Make sure to clean up and `Set rst = Nothing` as you close the parent form (in the Form_Unload event).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using 32 bit or 64 bit Access? If you are using 32 bit, then the bigint is 64 bit and 32 bit access cant handle it.